# Pagebreak en html2pdf no funciona

Tags: javascript, pdf

Estoy tratando de hacer un informe en pdf utilizando Html2Pdf junto con Html2Canvas en Javascript.
El informe tiene que tener varias páginas, así que estoy tratando de usar los pagebreaks. El problema esque después de haber probado mil cosas, no consigo hacer que aparezcan varias páginas.

Para las pruebas estoy utilizando este código en el HTML, tomado del típico ejemplo que aparece en todos los tutoriales:

```
<div id="report">
<div>First content</div>
<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>
<div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

Y el código de Javascript vendría a ser este:

```
function printReport() {
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    var docPDF = new jsPDF({
        orientation: "p",
/*        unit: "cm",*/
        format: "a4",

    });
    var elementHTML = document.getElementById("report").innerHTML;
    function save(docPDF) {

        docPDF.save("report.pdf");
    }

    docPDF.html(elementHTML, {
        callback: function (docPDF) {
            save(docPDF);
        },
        //x: 15,
        //y: 15,
        autoPaging: "text",
        width: docPDF.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
        height: docPDF.internal.pageSize.getHeight(),
        windowWidth: 650,
        pagebreak: { mode: ['css','legacy','avoid'] },
        margin: [5, 0, 5, 0],
        //putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
        });

}
```

Obra decir que en los modos de "pagebreak" he probado multitud de cosas, pero ninguna parece tener efecto.

En el Html, he probado con "before" y "after", pero tampoco surte efecto. Así mismo, he leido que html2pdf trae una clase llamada "html2pf__page-break", que te saca el salto de página automáticamente, pero tampoco parece tener efecto alguno.

Por último comentar que aunque estoy usando Javascript, el framework en el que trabajo es Blazor wasm, aunque dudo que esto tenga algo que ver.